# Database backup with no frozen I/O

Tags: sql-server, backup

Is there a way to make automated  backups of a DB without having the I/O frozen ?

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance .

*I/O is frozen on database distribution. No user action is required. However, if I/O is not resumed promptly, you could cancel the backup.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadow backups are taken by VSS backing up all the C: drive  lead into baking up the database and then lead into the I/O frozen message seen in the SQL server log.

The database backup when it is done normally via maintenance plan, via SQL Management Studio or via user  SQL query  does not generate I/O frozen message .